# Verify if a PDF is digitally signed with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

As the title says I want to know if a given PDF file is already digitally signed.

I used iText to sign it but I'm not able to know if it is already signed to eventually resign it or perform other actions.

Is there a way to do it simply (possibly using iText)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using iText:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(...);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
List<String> signatureNames = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
```

Now `signatureNames` contains the names of all reachable signature fields containing signatures, cf. the JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Gets the field names that have signatures and are signed.
 *
 * @return the field names that have signatures and are signed
 */
public ArrayList<String> getSignatureNames()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using newer iText version like 5.5.x here is a full working example how you can check a digitally signed PDF (a lot of useful development and changes have been done in iText since version 2.1.7):

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DigitalSignatureCheck {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DigitalSignatureCheck.class);

    public static final boolean verifySignature(PdfReader pdfReader)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        boolean valid = false;
        AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
        List<String> signatureNames = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
        if (!signatureNames.isEmpty()) {
            for (String name : signatureNames) {
                if (acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name)) {
                    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = acroFields.verifySignature(name);
                    valid = pkcs7.verify();
                    String reason = pkcs7.getReason();
                    Calendar signedAt = pkcs7.getSignDate();
                    X509Certificate signingCertificate = pkcs7.getSigningCertificate();
                    Principal issuerDN = signingCertificate.getIssuerDN();
                    Principal subjectDN = signingCertificate.getSubjectDN();
                    LOGGER.info("valid = {}, date = {}, reason = '{}', issuer = '{}', subject = '{}'",
                            valid, signedAt.getTime(), reason, issuerDN, subjectDN);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private static void validate(String name)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream is = DigitalSignatureCheck.class.getClassLoader()
                         .getResourceAsStream(name);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
        boolean ok = verifySignature(reader);
        LOGGER.info("'{}' is {}signed", name, ok ? "" : "NOT ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        validate("any.pdf"); // if placed in resources' root
    }
}
```

Using the LOGGER is just for displaying the result.

Comment: even if `ok` is `false`, the document most likely is signed (only not with a signature valid for the document), the signature merely does not refer to the document ite is embedded in, probably due to later changes.

Comment: my intention was to give just an example with the newest iText library (I am also has a current task to explore signed PDF documents) Of course you are right that is why I have included some additional attributes as well. You can check a lot of different aspect of the signature and you can make decision suitable for you. It was a simple deal just return with the verify() method result and say Yes or No.

Comment: The op wanted to *know if a given PDF file is already digitally signed*, not whether an existing signature is valid or whatever. So while it is nice to mention that one can retrieve numerous properties using current iText versions, an answer to this question should in particular be of interest in the context of the actual question.

Comment: What I do not understand how can be proved that a document is digitally signed if the signature attached to it is invalid or the document is changed after was signed. I think in both cases we can not say that the document is digitally signed. It was but after changing now it is not signed really. That is my opinion. I have read again the original question and still I feel my understanding was not bad. I have checked your profile and I see you have much more experience on PDF security than me but I feel my answer would help to @lgr. I hope.

Comment: The OP says *"I used iText to sign it but I'm not able to know if it is already signed to eventually resign it or perform other actions."* and asks *"Is there a way to do it simply?"* In my eyes this means that the OP is only interested in determining whether or not there is a digital signature in a document or not, he does not want to determine the validity or any other attributes thereof.

Comment: *I feel my answer would help to @lgr. I hope* - Considering he was last seen on stack overflow in 2014 I doubt that: Even if he still is following stack overflow questions and answers, he most likely implemented his task one way or another years ago and has moved on to other tasks.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Many thanks for your time and feedbacks.

Comment: All that being said you are definitely right that there were substantial advances between iText signature APIs  2.1.7 and 5.5.x.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem but I'm using itext 7 and there is no

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(...);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
```

in current version.

So I have used this solution [UPDATED]

```
private boolean hasSignatures(final PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
    final List<String> signatureNames = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument).getSignatureNames();
    return !signatureNames.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Beware, you merely test a flag from a flag field that *claims* that there are signatures, you don't check whether there actually are any. If you worked with the iText 7 `SignatureUtil`, you could get a solution actually checking for filled signature fields as the accepted answer here does.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for the remark. I have changed solution to use `SignatureUtil`

Comment: and how i can do if i want to retrieve DSS dictionary using this same function. By the way I'm trying to check if the revocation check has been done or not (knowing that I'm signing in Pades-LT)

Answer (score 2):

One example here

```
    public static final String verifSign(PdfReader pdfReader)
{
    KeyStore kall = PdfPKCS7.loadCacertsKeyStore();
    AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
    List<String> signatureNames = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
    if (signatureNames.isEmpty())
    {
        return ("El documento no tiene ni una firma registrada");
    }
    for(String name : signatureNames)
    {
        if (!acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name))
        {
            return ("la firma: "+name+" does not covers the whole document.");
        }
        PdfPKCS7 pk = acroFields.verifySignature(name);
        Certificate[] certificates = pk.getCertificates();
        Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
        //System.out.println("Document modified: " + !pk.verify());
        Object fails[] = PdfPKCS7.verifyCertificates(certificates, kall, null, cal);
        if (fails == null)
        {
            // Documento PDF firmado correctamente
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Firma no válida");
        }
    }
    // Todo firmado correctamente
    return null;
```

}

http://www.berthou.com/us/2009/07/01/verify-pdf-signature-with-itext/