# Digital Signature For PDF Documents

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pdfstamper

Is it possible to generate digital signature for already signed PDF document ? I am using following code to generate digital signature for PDF documents.

```
public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey 
   pk, String digestAlgorithm,String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter, 
   String reason, String location) {


        PdfReader reader;
        FileOutputStream os;
        PdfStamper stamper;

        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(src);
            File destFile = new File(dest);
            String destFilePath = destFile.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("destFilePath=====" + destFilePath);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            System.out.println("File output " + os);
            stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
            System.out.println("stamper " + stamper.getSignatureAppearance());
            // Creating the appearance
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
            System.out.println("Appearance " + appearance);
            // appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance("F:/Unibrain/EbidUploadedFolder/" +
            // "/resources/55.png"));
            appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance("F:\\55.png"));
            // appearance.setReason(reason);
            // appearance.setLocation(location);
            appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(800, 732, 512, 780), 1, "sig");
            appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
            appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
            Rectangle cropbox = reader.getCropBox(1);
            float width = 250;
            float height = 50;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(cropbox.getRight(width), cropbox.getBottom(), cropbox.getRight(),
                    cropbox.getBottom(height));
            cropbox.setBorderWidth(5);
            appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, 1, "sig");
            // Creating the signature
            ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            System.out.println("digest " + digest);
            ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
            System.out.println("Signature " + signature);
            MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse  Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate digital signature for already signed PDF document ?

In general yes but the additional signature must be added in an incremental update to not invalidate the pre-existing signature. For some backgrounds see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096).

In case of your code this means that you have to replace the line

```
stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
```

by

```
stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
```

The `true` indicates that the signature shall be applied in *append mode* which is iText lingo for adding changes in an incremental update.

Furthermore you have to make sure that the new signature is created in a different form field. Your code adds the signature into the had-coded field "sig":

```
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(800, 732, 512, 780), 1, "sig");
```

If you know that the name of the field of the pre-existing signature differs, this is ok. Otherwise you might want to replace "sig" by `null` which makes iText create a unique field name for the new signature.

---

Above I said "in general yes" - there is an exception, if the original signature is a certification signature with "no changes allowed", applying an additional signature will break the original signature as applying it is a change.

Comment: Thank You. And How to check whether PDF document is already signed or Not using iText library?

Comment: Thank You. How to check whether PDF document is already signed or Not using iText library?

Comment: @VIJAYAKUMAR *"How to check whether PDF document is already signed or Not using iText"* - cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446416/1729265)